# Java AWSClient reference in lambda

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using a lambda function written in java that listen to s3 bucket create object 
The requesthandler will call another class "testDownload" to download the object

something is happening when
`AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();`
is initialized, i am using it in a try catch block and checking if an exception is thrown and no error is displaying in cloud watch. Can you please help me understand whats going on

```
public class S3EventProcessor implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {
private final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
private final String ASSET_TYPE = (String) "jpg";
public String handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {
....
....
t.download(Bucket,Key);


import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class testDownload {
private final org.slf4j.Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

public void download(String bucketName,String key) throws IOException {


    try {
        logger.info("Downloading an object \n");
        logger.info("Building s3 client");
        AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
        logger.info("success");
        S3Object o = s3.getObject(bucketName, key);
        S3ObjectInputStream s3is = o.getObjectContent();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(key));
        byte[] read_buf = new byte[1024];
        int read_len = 0;
        while ((read_len = s3is.read(read_buf)) > 0) {
            fos.write(read_buf, 0, read_len);
        }
        s3is.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        logger.error(e.getErrorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (Exception e){
        logger.error(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

}

Cloud Logs

```
19:25:34,229 INFO testDownload:24 - Downloading an object 

19:25:34,229 INFO testDownload:25 - Building s3 client
END RequestId: someid
REPORT RequestId: someid    Duration:   3003.13 ms  Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory     Used: 52 MB  
2017-10-21T19:25:36.150Z someid Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

Comment: First off I suggest removing all the extra code that isn't relevant to the question. Basically all you want to know is why you're not getting an error logged when `AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build()` runs so you should trim the question down a lot. I suspect it might be that the cloud logs are swallowing the error or putting it somewhere else. Try putting a regular `logger.info` log into all of your `catch` statements and see if it picks those up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default timeout for a Lambda is 3 seconds.  Your Lambda runs for 3 seconds and then is killed.  Try to configure the Lambda to run longer.  Additionally, what are you trying to do with the output file - save it on the Lambda machine?

Comment: will try the time outway thanks ....and yes... i want to then upload to restapi... do you know if there is a way for aws to post a file directly to api (like facebook, you tube or spredfast) directly from s3 instead of downloading it to lambda machine and uploading as a file... i checked curl -F "@filepath" but it doesnt look like curl or something can help with uploading directly via s3 url

Comment: @JavaCode101pavan - I don't believe that there is a direct upload as there would be a bunch to configure for each service.  What you're doing makes the most sense but be careful on costs.  You've got the amount of time that it takes to download from S3 and then the amount of time to upload to another service.  Depending on the size of the files and speed of the services it could take some time.